# Constraint Layout with transparency and elevation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-elevation

I have 10 TextViews inside 1 Constraint Layout. What i would like to achieve is to have the Constraint Layout have some elevation to make it seem like all 10 textviews are basically above my background. But i would like to keep the background of my layout to take the background of the phone so have the Constraint layout have a transparent background. Any way i can achieve this?

I saw various posts here about this but they actually want the layout colored in and not transparent and that is where this one differs from theirs.

I have tried way to do it with shapes using a rectangle but the shadow of the elevation will only appear if i make the rectangle visible.... and not transparent.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/topBorder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvIon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/Ion"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvIonResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/ResultPlaceHolder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn1_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/sn1_1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvIon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn1_Result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/ResultPlaceHolder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvIonResult" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn1_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/sn1_3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn1_1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn1_3_Result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/ResultPlaceHolder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn1_Result" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn2_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/sn2_1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn1_3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn2_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/sn2_3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn2_1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn2_3_Result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/ResultPlaceHolder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn2_1_Result" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn2_1_Result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/ResultPlaceHolder"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn1_3_Result" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my xml for what i tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>
        <stroke android:color="#00000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: can you post a design of what you want

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a transparent activity on android
Add the following style in your ***res/values/styles.xml***

file Here’s a complete file:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" paren="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

then In the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <activity
    android:name=".WhateverNameOfTheActivityIs"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent">
    </activity>
```

If you **do not want** your layout to **be completely transparent**
then in your **layout** add this to **ConstraintLayout**

```
android:background="#80000000"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you add this line to the Constraint Layout xml it will become transparent: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`. This will make the background see through and show what ever is bellow or overlapping.